# how to use node-schedule to run a cron only on one instance?

Tags: node.js, cron, scheduled-tasks, multiple-instances

My question is how to use node-schedule to run a cron only on one instance out of two instances of node server.
Currently it is running on both instances but I want it to be executed only on one instance.
So How can you make a cluster run a task only once?
Thanks in advance.

```
{
  "apps": [
    {
      "name": "Example",
      "script": "boot/app/app.js",
      "watch": false,
      "exec_mode": "cluster_mode",
      "instances": 2,
      "merge_logs": true,
      "cwd": "/srv/www.example.com/server",
      "env": {
        "NODE_ENV": "development",
        .......
    .......
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use enviroment variables.

In your code you will check this env var:

```
if(process.env.WITH_SCHEDULE) {
    ...
}
```

When you start your instances, you will set WITH_SCHEDULE only for one instance.

Example pm2.json:

```
{
  "apps": [
    {
      "name": "Example",
      "script": "boot/app/app.js",
      "args": [],
      "error_file": "/srv/www.example.com/logs/error.log",
      "out_file": "/srv/www.example.com/logs/info.log",
      "ignore_watch": [
        "node_modules"
      ],
      "watch": false,
      "cwd": "/srv/www.example.com/server",
      "env": {
        "NODE_ENV": "production",
        "WITH_SCHEDULE": "1",
        "HOST": "127.0.0.1",
        "PORT": "9030"
      }
    },
    {
      "name": "Example",
      "script": "boot/app/app.js",
      "args": [],
      "error_file": "/srv/www.example.com/logs/error.log",
      "out_file": "/srv/www.example.com/logs/info.log",
      "ignore_watch": [
        "node_modules"
      ],
      "watch": false,
      "cwd": "/srv/www.example.com/server",
      "env": {
        "NODE_ENV": "production",
        "HOST": "127.0.0.1",
        "PORT": "9030"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: what if i don't know how many cores my machine has? i used to use **instance:"max"** in the configuration to create one instance for each core. Is a way to separate the main instance and other instance?

Comment: never mind, i figured it out. use **instance: -1** for other instance

Comment: But this will render one of the instances unusable for scheduling. And what if the scheduling instance dies? This defeats the purpose of distributed systems...
To make it robust and _the right way_ you should use either a central entity through which the instances will sync, or make them talk to each other and reach a consensus as to which one of them should schedule the task. The 1st option (central entity) is simpler and widely used. You can try this: https://github.com/thedeveloper/warlock

Answer (score 11):

You can use an environment variable provided by **PM2** itself called `NODE_APP_INSTANCE` which requires PM2 2.5.

`NODE_APP_INSTANCE` environment variable is used to determine difference between process, for example you may want to run a cronjob only on one process, you can just check if process.env.NODE_APP_INSTANCE === 0, Since two processes can never have the same number.

More Info on **PM2** official doc [here](http://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/environment/).

Comment: But how do we guarantee that one of the processes will have the ID 0. Is it not possible that if I run the app in cluster mode(2) they will have process IDs are 3 & 4 (assuming random numbers here)